# Change color of Picker Input in Shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinyjs

I'd like to modify the font color of the title of my Picker Input. I'm using spacelab theme, so the button is darkgrey, and the font color of the button is grey, so it's not really nice.

When I click on the button, or select some data, the font become white, so it's way better at this moment. When I modify the style color, the button is becoming white, even if I told him to be red. Example :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinyWidgets)
ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("spacelab"),
   pickerInput(
      inputId = "variable_list", choices = LETTERS, width = "60%", multiple = TRUE,
      options = list(size = 10, 'actions-box' = TRUE, 'live-search' = TRUE,
                     virtualScroll = TRUE, 
                     'none-selected-text'= strong("BUTTON TITLE:"), 
                     'selected-text-format'= "static")))

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a more straightforward way, but you could use `HTML` from `shiny` to add any formatting you want with HTML syntax, like this for example:

`'none-selected-text'=strong(HTML("<span style='color: white'>BUTTON TITLE:</span>"))`

**Edit**

Using wrapper functions from `shiny` and with the `center` tag:

```
strong(tag('center', list(span(style='color: white', 'BUTTON TITLE:'))))
```

Comment: It's perfect, thanks ! Do you know how to compilate several conditions in HTML syntax like that ? For example if I'd like to center the title on top of that?

Comment: sure just add center tag like this: `HTML("<center><span style='color: white'>BUTTON TITLE:</span></center>")`

Comment: Pleas see my edit as I just realised that it can be done with wrapper functions from `shiny`

Comment: It's perfect thank you very much, I really should go into some HTML. As it was impossible to make an ObserveEvent with PickerInput, I put it in a Dropdown. So the choices list is generate only when I click on the DropDown button. Another thing, is HTML code can change the background color of my app ? Or I don't have the choice but to create a CSS file outside of my app (in \www)?

Comment: `shinyWidgets`  has a function `setBackgroundColor`, with which you can change the background color : https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shinyWidgets/versions/0.4.5/topics/setBackgroundColor

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you very much ! :)